# Append "blank bytes" to a binary?

Tags: byte, filesize

I want to increase the file size of a binary without damaging how it works. If I read it correctly there are such things as "blank bytes" that do nothing but still add to the file size all the same. Can anyone give me an idea of how it is done or what tools I would need?

Comment: That really depends on what file you're working on.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how slow this computer can get if a large executable is running. That's why I want to do it.

Comment: For executables files, it depends whether it need to read it own EXE file or not. For example, an application installer EXE. Modifying such file without any knowledge of how the program reads the file would likely to break the program's functionality. For executables that doesn't need to read it's own EXE file such as *Notepad*, you can append anything at the end of it using any hex editor. Keep in mind that some EXE files has digital signature and it may fail to run since editing it would break the signature.

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing the executable file with a HEX editor and it seems most common hex editors nowadays have the option to insert the said blank bytes. So yeah, that sorted out my problem.